# how to Implement replication_pad2d layer in to coremltools converters as torch_op

Tags: pytorch, coreml, coremltools

I've been trying to convert my pytorch model into coreML format, However one of the layers is currently not supported [replication_pad2d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ReplicationPad2d.html). Therefore I was trying to implement it using the register operator decorator `@register_torch_op`  to reimplement the layer for coremltools.converters, However I'm struggling to understand the input types to be able to implement the function currently. I got this, which is an implementation roughly translated from pytorch but it's not working

```
from coremltools.converters.mil import Builder as mb
from coremltools.converters.mil import register_torch_op
from coremltools.converters.mil.frontend.torch.ops import _get_inputs

@register_torch_op
def replication_pad2d(context, node):
  inputs = _get_inputs(context, node)
  x = inputs[0]
  a = len(x)
  L_list, R_list = [], []
  U_list, D_list = [], []
  for i in range(a):#i:0, 1
    l = x[:, :, :, (a-i):(a-i+1)]
    L_list.append(l)
    r = x[:, :, :, (i-a-1):(i-a)]
    R_list.append(r)
  L_list.append(x)
  x = mb.concat(L_list+R_list[::-1], axis=3, name=node.name)
  for i in range(a):
    u = x[:, :, (a-i):(a-i+1), :]
    U_list.append(u)
    d = x[:, :, (i-a-1):(i-a), :]
    D_list.append(d)
  U_list.append(x)
  x = mb.concat(U_list+D_list[::-1], axis=3, name=node.name)
  context.add(x)
```

but getting the following error

```
<ipython-input-12-cf14ed84cb93> in replication_pad2d(context, node)
     59   inputs = _get_inputs(context, node)
     60   x = inputs[0]
---> 61   a = len(x)
     62   L_list, R_list = [], []
     63   U_list, D_list = [], []

TypeError: object of type 'Var' has no len()
```

would be great if someone could help me understand this better especially input type node and context

Comment: This stuff is largely undocumented and I'm afraid you'll have to dig through the coremltools source code to make any sense of this. However, I'm afraid your current approach won't work anyway: as far as I know, *all* operations need to be expressed using `mb`. But you're building a Python list to capture intermediate results. The `Builder` object will never see this. Instead of writing something like `l = x[:, :, :, (a-i):(a-i+1)]` you'll have to use something like `mb.split()`, and so on. (I haven't used this in detail yet myself, so I could be mistaken about some of this.)

Comment: However, Core ML does have a `PaddingReplication` mode in its existing padding layer. Perhaps the easier solution is to "hack" coremltools into supporting this mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the you can use the existing padding layer as:

```
from coremltools.converters.mil import Builder as mb
from coremltools.converters.mil import register_torch_op
from coremltools.converters.mil.frontend.torch.ops import _get_inputs

@register_torch_op(torch_alias=["replication_pad2d"])
def HackedReplication_pad2d(context, node):
    inputs = _get_inputs(context, node)
    x = inputs[0]
    pad = inputs[1].val
    x_pad = mb.pad(x=x, pad=[pad[2], pad[3], pad[0], pad[1]], mode='replicate')
    context.add(x_pad, node.name)
```

The documentation of the padding operation is not that great, so ordering of padding parameters is a guessing game.